# Proof that limit of convergent sequence lies in $[a,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, which converges, and has $a_n \in [a,\infty)$.  I need to prove that the limit of $a_n$ lies in $[a,\infty)$.

I thought that doing this by contradiction would be the best way to go.  I said that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = L$.  $L$ should be in $[a,\infty)$ (with all the other elements of $a_n$).

For the contradiction, I'm saying that $L \notin [a,\infty)$.  If this is the case, then $L \in (-\infty, a)$

So I figured to get the contradiction, I would use this 'fact' about L, and then find that the sequence does not converge if that's the case, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I've tried using the $\epsilon - N$ definition of a limit but that didn't really get me anywhere.

Thanks for your time

Comment: If $L\notin [a,+\infty)$ then $(-\infty,a)$ is an open neighborhood of $L$ that doesn't contain any point of the sequence. Contradiction, since every neighborhood of the limit should contain almost all points of the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the way to go. Take $\varepsilon=a-L$. This makes sense, because $a-L>0$. Now, let $N\in\mathbb N$. Then there's a $n\geqslant N$ such that $|a_n-L|\geqslant\varepsilon$. Indeed, you can take $n=N$, because$$L<a\leqslant a_n\implies|a_n-L|=a_n-L=\overbrace{a_n-a}^{\phantom{0}\geqslant0}+a-L\geqslant a-L=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm a bit confused though, isn't the definition of a limit such that $|a_n-L| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Yes. And what I proved was that $L$ is **not** the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

$$ L <a \implies  a-L =\epsilon >0 $$

Consider $$  B= (L-\epsilon /2,L+\epsilon /2 ) $$

No term of your sequence  are included in $B$

That contradicts the fact that  $ a_n \to L$